# Remove String spaces with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am going to remove the first index space and last index spaces via python's `re` feature:

I tried:

```
    re.sub(r"\s+" ,""," hello world ") // remove the first place space
```

But it does not removed any thing.

Comment: @VigneshKalai I want to use `re` specially.

Comment: `/^\s|\s$/g` https://regex101.com/r/iQ6eE8/1

Comment: @VigneshKalai The question title says it `...with regular expression`

Comment: It removes *every* space

Comment: Your snippet actually removes every whitespace.

Comment: What version of Python do you have - my copy of Python 2.7.3 gives `'helloworld'` in response to `re.sub(r"\s+", "", " hello world ")`. While that doesn't exactly match your stated goal (which would be better achieved with `strip()`, as already mentioned), it does in fact remove the spaces from the string...

Comment: @twalberg Yes, it removes all the spaces, i had a mistake, i write: `sub(...)` and then return the text variable in the next line and it gives me the input value exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> re.sub(r'^\s+|\s+$', '', ' hello world ')
'hello world'
```

That will remove all leading and trailing whitespaces, though, not necessarily only the first and last index.